# Contact form 7 to Spam Folders

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I've tried almost all of the solutions found online

- I also have my proper website email on FROM which is `<contact@mydomain.com>`, there for I have `[Fullname] <contact@mydomain.com>` on my FROM section
- I also have reCaptcha installed
- I also tried SMTP plugin
- I also tried Honeypot

**STILL MY EMAILS ARE GOING TO SPAM!**

*I don't know what to do*

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your domain has a proper SPF record that includes your servers IP address or name.  Especially if it's different than your mail host.

https://mxtoolbox.com/SPFRecordGenerator.aspx

Set at your DNS server a txt record something like:

`v=spf1 a:server.yourdomain.com ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ~all`

Comment: how would know if i have proper spf after using that generator? and where do I set this DNS code?

Comment: If you don't have one, or if you do... this tool will tell you.  You have to add it to your DNS record. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784415/how-to-properly-set-up-dns-spf-records